# Dart DateTime .difference

Tags: datetime, dart, difference

I want to set a timer to run once every minute, while I was writing the programm I found this unexpected behaviour

```
void main() {
  final now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
  final minuteAfterNow = new DateTime(now.year,now.month,now.day,now.hour,now.minute +1,now.second,now.millisecond,now.microsecond);
  print(minuteAfterNow);
  print(now);
  print(minuteAfterNow.difference(now));
}
```

The output is the following:

2020-12-30 09:41:06.508
2020-12-30 09:40:06.508Z
-1:59:00.000000

Shouldn't the difference output 1 minute? What's with this output?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please write you code and output as text instead of attaching an image.

Comment: 1. One `DateTime` is in local time, and the other is in UTC. 2. You ignored seconds. And, as mentioned, don't post screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is different because there are 2 issues:

1/ You are comparing between UTC and non UTC, that will take extra offset :). I will altenate you code and let you see by yourself:

```
 final now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
 final now1 = DateTime.utc(now.year, now.month, now.day,now.hour, now.minute, now.second + 1, now.millisecond, now.microsecond);
 final difference = now.difference(now1);
 print(difference);
```

2/ You missed the second, millisecond, microsecond parameters. Once you ignore it, it will be zero by default. Please take a look at the DateTime class in Dart

```
  DateTime.utc(int year,
      [int month = 1,
      int day = 1,
      int hour = 0,
      int minute = 0,
      int second = 0,
      int millisecond = 0,
      int microsecond = 0])
      : this._internal(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond,
            microsecond, true);
```

Btw, please add your code next time. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I expected the difference function to calculate only the difference between two dates not checking if they are Utc or not which is not true

```
 external DateTime._internal(int year, int month, int day, int hour,
      int minute, int second, int millisecond, int microsecond, bool isUtc);
```

that is why the below code gives a desired output, even though the dates where the same before.

```
final now = DateTime.now();
  final now2 = now.toUtc();
  final minuteAfterNow = new DateTime(now.year,now.month,now.day,now.hour,now.minute +1,now.second,now.millisecond,now.microsecond).toUtc();
  print(minuteAfterNow);
  print(now2);
  print(minuteAfterNow.difference(now2).inMinutes);
```

outputs:
2020-12-30 09:37:52.559Z
2020-12-30 09:36:52.559Z
1